# Accessing variables in other functions in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

<strike>I have recently installed Visual Studio Code on my Raspberry Pi (or Code-OSS by headmelted) and I've "connected" it with mono to create and run a WinForms application. However, I always use Visual Studio to create WinForms applications and I don't know how to add buttons and labels to a WinForms application. I live in China and don't have any access to Google or YouTube. I've tried searching on Bing, but most websites are blocked.</strike>

**EDIT**: I've successfully made a window, but I can't seem to access it in other functions... Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
        password = textbox.Text;
        if(password == "mypassword"){
            stateLabel.Text = "Password is correct";
        }else{
            stateLabel.Text = "Password is incorrect";
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var window = new Form();
        window.Text = "Login";
        window.Height = 130;
        window.Width = 365;
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        Label passwordLabel = new Label();
        Button passwordButton = new Button();
        Label stateLabel = new Label();

        stateLabel.Text = "Please enter your password";
        passwordLabel.Text = "Password";
        passwordButton.Text = "Login";

        passwordLabel.Location = new Point(25, 30);
        textbox.Location = new Point(125, 25);
        passwordButton.Location = new Point(260, 25);
        stateLabel.Location = new Point(125, 60);
        passwordButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(clicked);

        window.Controls.Add(textbox);
        window.Controls.Add(passwordLabel);
        window.Controls.Add(passwordButton);
        window.Controls.Add(stateLabel);
        Application.Run(window);
    }
}
```

When I run it, it just gives me an error saying that "window" is not defined in the clicked function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add controls to form programmatically by creating an instance of that control and adding it to `Controls` collection

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.Location = new Point(25,25);
this.Controls.Add (textbox);
```

You can add other controls in a similar way.

To find more about that you can also check [this Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-controls-to-windows-forms)

Comment: Your code works! I had to add System.Drawing.dll to the mcs compiler and `using System.Drawing`. Thanks a LOT!